Bug in scene camera?
In the Scene tab, where the dropdown value can be used to set active camera, I keep getting an object from my scene called Circle instead of a camera. I'll press the cross to delete the Circle object from the Scene tab's camera value, add the actual camera, save, and a few minutes later when I render it'll be showing the Circle object as the camera again and nothing will render.
Have tried setting camera through the View menu > "Set active object as camera" too, but it didn't make any difference.

Any ideas?

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload images or gifs, along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

When you switch one editor window to the Timeline, you will see that there is a camera marker set on frame 98 named "Circle" (that is your hat object which is not renamed to something more self-explanatory).
Now with these camera markers it is like animation keyframes: an object (or the scene setting) switches to the values stored in the keyframe/marker on that frame, however if there is no keyframe/marker before this one with a different value, the value is valid from the beginning up unto this frame (and gets changed or not depending on what's following the keyframe).

Like other animation keyframes, you can change values directly on an object (or scene in this case) and they will show in the 3D Viewport, but when it comes down to rendering, only values defined by keyframes will be acknowledged.
Which means, no matter which object you set as camera, the render will only use the one defined by the marker unless you either would set a marker for the correct camera object or just delete the incorrect marker so that Blender always uses the active camera you have chosen.
To get rid of the marker, hover your mouse over the camera symbol and press X > Delete Markers.

Now it can be that deleting the marker refreshes Blender's viewport with the last known (fixed by marker) value, so you're back to the "Circle" object again. But if you now change the camera back to the real camera object by either selecting it in the Scene tab or by selecting the camera and pressing Ctrl+Numpad 0 if will not change the camera anymore and use it for rendering.
By the way, when the hat is selected as camera, the scene is not empty because it is not rendering, it is empty because the view direction of a camera object is its local -Z direction, in case of the hat it is pointing downwards, but there are no objects and you have set the background to transparent, so and empty scene is all the hat camera sees.
